# Clarification of NIST Digital Identify Guidelines and "Pepper" in Password Hashing

Tags: password-hashing

For password hashing the [NIST Digital Identity Guidelines](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf) state

> In addition, verifiers SHOULD perform an additional iteration of a key derivation function using a salt value that is secret and known only to the verifier. This salt value, if used, SHALL be generated by an approved random bit generator [SP 800-90Ar1] and provide at least the minimum security strength specified in the latest revision of SP 800-131A (112 bits as of the date of this publication). The secret salt value SHALL be stored separately from the hashed
>   memorized secrets (e.g., in a specialized device like a hardware security module). With this additional iteration, brute-force attacks on the hashed memorized secrets are impractical as long as the secret salt value remains secret.

This additional salt is typically referred to as "pepper" in most literature.  The thing is that the NIST document says "an additional iteration" as if it's a single iteration of the hash function adding in this data.  However, most of the implementations I've seen concatenate the salt and the pepper to create the salt value that the hashing function uses.

Am I right that NIST guidance is to do a single additional iteration?  And if so, is there a difference in real world security between the two?

Comment: If you asked this in Information Security you will get an answer immediately. `seems like how the algorithm works is crypto, how the algorithm is used is Security and how the algorithm is implemented is StackOverflow.`

Comment: @kelalaka we should add that to crypto.SE's description...

Comment: @Legorooj I've posted the original quote in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52903807#52903807).